# Doctrine 2.0 - Semantical Error

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I'm trying to map my entities but I always get this error when I do a schema:update, drop or create. So I tried many solutions like adding this line to my autoload.php:

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php');
```

but it still doesn't work... here's the code in conflict:
**File Entity:**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\OnetoMany(targetEntity="Intranet\ExampleBundle\Entity\File_Liaison", mappedBy="idFile", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="idFile")
 */
    private $id;
```

**File_Liaison Entity:**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne (targetEntity="Intranet\ExampleBundle\Entity\File", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn (name="idFile", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $idFile;
```

And here's the error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OnetoMany" in property Intranet\ExampleBundle\Entity\File::$id does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

I read many topics about this problem but I didn't find anything that works.
Thank you for your help ! :-)

Comment: Could you please provide whole error text?

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are trying to add a relationship in which one File has many File_liaison so the File side should have a collection of File_liaison. Which is not the case as `$id` cannot be both an auto generated integer and a collection of entities.

Try cleaning up `$id` and adding a property in your File entity, something like

```
/**
 * @ORM\OnetoMany(targetEntity="Intranet\ExampleBundle\Entity\File_Liaison", mappedBy="idFile", cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 */
    private $liaisons;
```

Then implement appropriate addLiaison, removeLiaison and getLiaisons methods

```
/**
 * Add liaison
 *
 * @param \Intranet\ExampleBundle\Entity\File_Liaison $liaison
 */
public function addLiaison(\Intranet\ExampleBundle\Entity\File_Liaison $liaison)
{
    $this->liaisons[] = $liaison;
}

/**
 * Get liaisons
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getLiaisons()
{
    return $this->liaisons;
}
```

And finally update the File_liaison inversedBy for the `$idFile`

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne (targetEntity="Intranet\ExampleBundle\Entity\File", inversedBy="liaisons")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn (name="idFile", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $idFile;
```

Obviously this is not tested, but it should give you a pretty good idea of what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help ! 
The error was still appearing but I resolved the problem ! Something was wrong with the File Entity. I changed it:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @var integer
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="refFile", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Intranet\ExampleBundle\Entity\File_Liaison", mappedBy="idFile", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idFile", referencedColumnName="refFile")
 */
private $refFile;
```